# Package installation python - Dom.pulldom error

Tags: python, anaconda

I try to install a package which works well on another PC but when I cmd the install I get following errors.

Has someone any idea on honw to correct this error ?

```
C:\Users\events\distribution\events-0.1\events-0.1>python setup.py install
running install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    keywords = ""
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\setuptools\comman
d\install.py", line 67, in run
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\setuptools\comman
d\install.py", line 98, in do_egg_install
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.p
y", line 388, in get_command_class
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py"
, line 2171, in load
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\setuptools\comman
d\easy_install.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\setuptools\comman
d\egg_info.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\setuptools\comman
d\sdist.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg\setuptools\svn_ut
ils.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dom.pulldom
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using anaconda, you should probably use its install tool. Try one of the following instead:

```
conda install events
```

or

```
conda install Events-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

Or whatever the tar file you downloaded is called. See also:

- http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda